# Smooth circular data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, smoothing

I have an array of data `Y` such that `Y` is a function of an independent variable `X` (another array).

The values in `X` vary from 0 to 360, with wraparound.

The values in `Y` vary from -180 to 180, also with wraparound.

(That is, these values are angles in degrees around a circle.)

Does anyone know of any function in Python (in `numpy`, `scipy`, etc.) capable of low-pass filtering my `Y` values as a function of `X`?

In case this is at all confusing, here's a plot of example data:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to handle the wrapping around?  If X wraps around from 359 deg. to 001 deg., should the Y value be smoothed with other data near 001 deg.?  Or should the Y value be treated as though it were at 361 deg.?  Similarly, how do you want to handle wrap-around of Y?

Comment: The problem says there are two arrays X and Y, where Y[i] is a function  of X[i].  I was presuming i represented time.  My question is if Y has a sequence that looks like [..., 179, 180, -179, -178, 177, ...] does it make more sense to treat it literally, or like it contained [..., 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, ...].  Similarly for X.  In my answer below, I "unwrap" the data before smoothing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you start with

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 360, 360)
y = 5 * np.sin(x / 90. * 3.14) + np.random.randn(360)

plot(x, y, '+');
```

[image]

To perform a circular convolution, you can do the following:

```
yy = np.concatenate((y, y))
smoothed = np.convolve(np.array([1] * 5), yy)[5: len(x) + 5]
```

This uses, at each point, the cyclic average with the previous 5 points (inclusive). Of course, there are other ways of doing so.

```
>>> plot(x, smoothed)
```

[image]

Comment: note that this doesn't deal with the wraparound in the `y` values -- but that's OK here because they never obtain values close to the wraparound point (+/- 180).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using pandas to do a moving average.  First `unwrap` the data (need to convert to radians and back), so there are no discontinuities (e.g., jump from 180 to -179).  Then compute the moving average and finally convert back to wrapped data if desired.  Also, check out this [numpy cookbook recipe](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/SignalSmooth.html) using `np.convolve()`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate random data
X = pd.Series([(x  + 5*np.random.random())%360       for x in range(-100, 600, 15)])
Y = pd.Series([(y  + 5*np.random.random())%360 - 180 for y in range(-200, 500, 15)])

# 'unwrap' the angles so there is no wrap around
X1 = pd.Series(np.rad2deg(np.unwrap(np.deg2rad(Y))))
Y1 = pd.Series(np.rad2deg(np.unwrap(np.deg2rad(Y))))

# smooth the data with a moving average
# note: this is pandas 17.1, the api changed for version 18
X2 = pd.rolling_mean(X1, window=3)
Y2 = pd.rolling_mean(Y1, window=3)

# convert back to wrapped data if desired
X3 = X2 % 360
Y3 = (Y2 + 180)%360 - 180
```

Comment: i don't see the sense in smoothing `X1`.  that's my independent variable.  no uncertainty there.  above, you were thinking of `X` and `Y` as functions of time, but that's not the right way to think about it.  like i said, `Y` is a function of `X`.  `X` is the stand-in for time here.

Comment: p.s. thanks for pointing out `np.unwrap`.  i wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convolve2D` from `scipy.signal`. Here is a function, which applies smoothing to a numpy array `a`. If `a` has more than one dimension smoothing is applied to the innermost (fastest) dimension.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

def cyclic_moving_av( a, n= 3, win_type= 'boxcar' ):
  window= signal.get_window( win_type, n, fftbins=False ).reshape( (1,n) )
  shp_a= a.shape
  b= signal.convolve2d( a.reshape( ( np.prod( shp_a[:-1], dtype=int ), shp_a[-1] ) ), 
                        window, boundary='wrap', mode='same' )
  return ( b / np.sum( window ) ).reshape( shp_a )
```

For instance it can be used like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 360, 360)
y1 = 5 * np.sin(x / 90. * 3.14) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(360)
y2 = 5 * np.cos(0.8 * x / 90. * 3.14) + 0.5 * np.random.randn(360)

y_av=  cyclic_moving_av( np.stack((y1,y2)), n=10 )  #1

plt.plot(x, y1, '+')
plt.plot(x, y2, '+')
plt.plot(x, y_av[0])
plt.plot(x, y_av[1])
plt.show()
```

This results in
[image: Cyclic smoothed data]

Line `#1` is equivalent to

```
y_av[0]=  cyclic_moving_av( y1, n=10 )
y_av[1]=  cyclic_moving_av( y2, n=10 )
```

`win_type= 'boxcar'` results in averaging over neighbors with equal weights. See [signal.get_window](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.get_window.html) for other options.